# How do i change the google cardboard stereo-view to a mono-view

Tags: android, view, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

So I would like to change the view in the google `Cardboard` demo-app to a mono-view. So that instead of displaying a image on each half of the handy-screen for each eye I want to display only one image that fills the complete screen. Any ideas how I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Android SDK, you call `setVRModeEnabled(false)` on the CardboardView object.

In the Unity SDK, you set `VRModeEnabled = false` on the Cardboard.SDK object.